# Repairing Word hyperlinks to internal document headings

Tags: microsoft-word

I have an 800pg manual in Word with many internal hyperlinks. I switched the order of a few small sections a few weeks ago by copy and paste within the document; I recently discovered that many hyperlinks show as file:///C:.... references, not Current Document, and some don't work. In ALT-F9 mode, they all show as {HYPERLINK \I "_whatever..."}.   I can make them work one-by-one by bringing up the control-K dialog, clicking Place in This Document, and locating the corresponding section (an incredibly slow and painful process). That sometimes adds an "_1" to the hyperlink text, in some I looked at.  I need to be able to automatically find all the ***non-functional internal hyperlinks***, and preferably correct them (since the section names still exist). Is there some VB for this? Or even a good explanation of what happened and what might allow it to be fixed? Spending literal weeks for manual repair isn't an option. (Current Word, Version 2209 15629.20156)

Comment: Automatically created links, as in links to headings are invisible and the names start with an underscore. The first step is to set your options in Word to make hyperlinks visible. When you add text at the beginning of a heading, then hit Enter and reformat your text as non-heading, the added text will be inside the link. When you move headings, use the Navigation Pane to do it. When you want to type something before a heading, go to the end of the preceding paragraph, press Enter and create a new paragraph that is outside the bookmark.

Comment: There is no tool or vba to fix this of which I am aware. You need to be aware of where the bookmarks are when you edit and move the bookmark appropriately or regenerate the link and bookmark. See the section on Working with Bookmarks here: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA.htm

Answer (score 0):

Normally I'd hesitate to give an answer without more substance, but seeing as no one has even so much as commented on this one, I thought I'd contribute what I can just to help you along in the interim!

First thing's first: <s>although I couldn't say what the cause is for your links becoming broken,</s> Your links are breaking due to the underscore "_" being prepended to them; I mention in more detail below, but they need to **begin with a letter**, and then only contain **alphanumeric** characters.  I'd recommend you establish a method to apply some sort of logical convention(s) to your file naming, storage, access, etc.  This will vary *greatly* depending on a variety of variables, such as the setting of your use, e.g., office/clerical/admin?  Domain or local-only?  File-server, on-site/offsite? or SMB share?  Security considerations?  Do you have decision making rights?  In-house IT or contracted?  Etc, etc.  However, just to give some examples:

- If you have a domain-based setup with a file-server, always try to keep in mind: **who** should or should not have access to this data?  And from where will they be expected to access it?  If the setting is for a small office with domain and on-site file-server and there are no particularly stringent restrictions in place for data security, then I'd recommend mapping storage locations to named, shared directories.  This will allow you to directly manage access permissions by directory, and also enable you to access the files from a centralized location so there are no concerns regarding version control (though workplace training and culture still plays a major role in that regard).
- Once you create a shared directory, try to make a habit of crafting your links in such manner as to enable agnostic access (as allowed by your security policies in place), i.e., can be opened from Work Station A or Work Station B, as well as from Device C, etc.  For example, if you hyperlink to `C:\Users\<username>\Documents\File`, it would make it difficult for the file to be opened from other workstations due to the varying usernames deployed at each workstation.  Even considering `%username%` variable paths and proper access credentialing in domain environment, it would be contingent upon each station being Windows-based and having their env paths deployed in consistent manner, and/or having to have your IT update them by request assuming you don't have the access or knowledge yourself (though sometimes the ensuing delay can't be avoided regardless of that knowledge).  If you reference the same file using a UNC path instead though, e.g., `\\TeamA\Documents\File`, the same hyperlink written as-is will open from *any* device within the domain (presuming they've been granted the necessary permissions *and/or* given the necessary credentials).
- Regarding hyperlinks that have a `file:///` protocol, I recommend you avoid these as they are commonly restricted due to recent security policy paradigms and the involved vulnerabilities associated with them.
- If you find having to modify hyperlinks each time to be tedious, there should be *many* different methods to improve your office QOL (again, as your usage setting permits).  Just as an example, I used to use a program called [AHK](https://www.autohotkey.com/), which can be fully portable if compiled (or accessed from server), which I carried on my person via a USB "key" (mine was one both in shape as well as function).  With it, you can define "hotstrings" which will automatically take any shorthand you've defined and replace it with another string; e.g., you can define a rule where whenever you type `!TA`, it will automatically replace that text with `\\TeamA\`, or etc.  The neat thing about AHK is you can also create hotkeys to invoke inputs, and that inputs can likewise include key inputs, not just character strings.  This can be paired with a "helper" program to invoke with more ease (such as [RainMeter](https://www.rainmeter.net) or even Excel), and you can also circumvent certain access issues by sending inputs as literal key input macros (i.e., the program treats inputs the same as if someone had typed or clicked them physically, as opposed to using say a VB script and expecting the current workstation to be configured with the necessary permissions to run it "out-of-box", so to speak).
- Regarding your current issue of saving time and efforts to audit your links, one method I can recommend would be to utilize another program to  modify the content.  For example, [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/) (which is open-source) includes a search-and-replace function that can optionally utilize [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) search format.  Find a commonality in the links you need to have fixed that can be expressed formulaecally, i.e., sharing a common feature or logical/formatting convention that can be mathematically addressed.  Even if you aren't familiar with regex, you can still get by by checking all entries that match your constraints prior to executing, then paste back into your Word document.  For example, find `file:///c:\users\<user>\Documents\` and replace with `\\TeamA\Documents\`.
- In regards to internal links (i.e., links to bookmarks/headings), there are some rules to the string formatting used to reference the headings, e.g., having to start with a letter, containing only alphanumeric characters, no spaces, etc.  Assuming these are being observed, you should be able to denote the section in question by appending `#section_name` to your hyperlink, where section_name is the name of the bookmark being referenced.  So for example, `\\TeamA\Documents\File.docx#Section`.  Note: This should apply when opening with Word or as .pdf file, and saving the file as a .pdf should retain the links.  However, in certain cases such as with dynamic styling, changes can break the links and there doesn't appear to be an easy fix out-of-box other than manual intervention.  Personally, I historically utilized Excel more often than Word, which had much more functional flexibility when it came to dynamic links.  I wasn't aware until just a few moments ago, but it appears .docx files lack the ability to process URI query strings, e.g., `.\file.xlsx&activeCell=SheetName!CellNumber`, which I find to be an odd disparity within the same software suite.  I'm unable to test further at the moment, but I would suspect there should be some method to achieve similar effects; the .docx container itself is simply a compressed archive consisting of various .xml files, I'll have to take another look as it's been a while since I last worked with them.

Disclaimer: Some of my knowledge can be dated, not be optimal in efficacy, or specific to a particular use setting, so YMMV, but I should hope that at the very least you can leverage any part of it as to avoid the worse-case you mentioned?  Good luck!

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear. This answer is far off base. The question concerns internal links to section headings. The names starting with underscore are all generated by Word itself in response to control-K, Place In Document, select a section. There are no servers involved, or any other files --- everything at issue is internal to this one document. Thanks for the impressive effort though.

Comment: Automatically generated links as in to headings or cross-references are prepended with an underscore automatically. They are hidden links. This is not what causes them to break.